# how to define the _udn in the GA?

Tags: google-analytics

the domain name in _udn should be with dot in front or not?
Examples:
_udn = ".site.com"
_udn = "site.com"

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to include subdomains, then, yes, with a dot.

e.g.

_udn="site.com"  will not register analytics from www.site.com

_udn=".site.com" will

Answer (score 0):

Both work, with limitations on 'work' - the no-dot works well for single-level subdomains, but sometimes gets confused by multiple levels of subdomain. The dot version works well for all subdomains, *but* changes the way the cookies are matched, and then all existing cookies will be ignored - so all existing users will be treated as new users.

Extra for experts:

1. The no-dot version gets a dot added when being used as the domain value for the cookies, so it does match www.site.com
2. By default, the 'www.' is stripped from the domain, so site.com & www.site.com are treated equally.
3. The cookie value starts with a hash of the domain name (but strips off the leading 'www.').  The _udn var (and _setDomainName function) provides an alternative input value for the hash, which is why the user IDs are changed. This domain-name hash can be disabled if required.
4. In any case you should check your changes - easiest is with Firebug's Net panel, or a proxy like Charles.